# What does そんなことで mean in this context?

Tags: reading-comprehension

> パソコンは、できる人にとったら**そんなことで**？と思うかもしれないですね。
>
> でも、主さんも、やっときますからは、ちょっと違うかなぁ？と思います。([source](https://mikle.jp/threadres/2673152/p1/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

そんなことで means "such a (little) thing".

The first sentence means "People who are good with personal computers may think that you don't ask me how to use personal computers such a little thing".